# Rounding up to the nearest tenth

Tags: matlab, floating-point, rounding

I am trying to round up the `cx_n` to its nearest number if the `cx_n` value doesn't match with `yt`. With the code below, I can round up but it goes all the way to 1. For example,
one of the `cx_n` values is 0.58, I want to round up 0.6, not 1.0. How can I accomplish this?

This is my MATLAB Code:

```
Fn = 3; %Nyquist Frequency
Fnr = 6; %Nyquist Rate
Fs = Fnr*5; %Sampling frequency
Ts = 1 / Fs; %Sampling period
T = 1 / 3; 
N = T / Ts; %Number of samples per period
start = 0;
stop =N-1;
c_increment = 1;
c_n = start:c_increment:stop;
c_nTs = c_n*Ts;
cx_n = sin(2*pi*3*c_nTs);
for m_d = 1:length(cx_n)
    for quantisation = 1:length(yt)
        if (m_d ~= quantisation )
            p = round(cx_n);
            stem(c_nTs, p);
        end
        
    end
end
```

Comment: To round up to the nearest tenth: `x = 0.58; y = ceil(x*10)/10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace  `p = round(cx_n);` with  `p = round(cx_n,1);`

[image: stem graph]

See MATLAB documentation: [round](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html)

> Y = round(X,N) rounds to N digits:
>
> - N > 0: round to N digits to the right of the decimal point.
> - N = 0: round to the nearest integer.
> - N < 0: round to N digits to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But it didn't work. If you give a close look at the graph, you should be able to see that it didn't round up. Say, the first value should be 0.6 but it is 0.59.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `p = round(cx_n,1);` then... Didn't check the numbers on my first answer. But this should work as expected? I edited the first answer with screenshot

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Have a good one!